# Is there a function ( not $f(x) = aX+b$) with first derivative " non zero " and second derivative $= 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following true or false? Justify.

> If $f''(x)=0$ for all $x \in E$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in E$, then $f(x)=ax+b.$

Comment: What have *you* tried? What are *your* thoughts? Where are *you* stuck?

Comment: What is E here?

Comment: Is $E$ a connected set?

Comment: E is any set you want @SahibaArora

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the fundamental theorem of calculus twice.

Answer (score 2):

> Since you mentioned in comments that $E$ is any set **I** want, so I will take it to be connected.

You have $f''(x)=0$ for all $x \in E$ and $E$ is connected, therefore, $f'$ is constant (say $a$) on $E.$

Since, $f'(x)=a$ for all $x \in E$, therefore, $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x \in E$ for some contant $b.$

> This is not true if $E$ is not connected.

Let $E=[0,1] \cup [3,5].$ Define $f: E \to \mathbb R$ as 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x+1,&x \in [0,1]\\3x+2, &x\in[3,5]\end{cases}$$Then $f''(x)=0$ for all $x \in E.$ But $f$ is not of the form $ax+b.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
What can you say about the first derivative if the second derivative is a zero function? What can you then say about the function itself?